# How to send a file from URL through POST request using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

The endpoint what I'm using works fine when I tested it in this way:

```
curl -X POST ".../api/save" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@test.xlsx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Now I need to send the file using Guzzle in Laravel, but I got 400 Bad Request from the API endpoint. The file is stored in the public disk, so I'm sending the URL.

This is what I have so far:

```
   $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ];

    $response = $this->client->request('POST', '.../api/save', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => 'image_file',
                'contents' => $file->url,
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: anyone who likes sloths has my vote

Comment: Check this, might help -> https://youtu.be/6CJ73IImcAY?t=206

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is breaking some http protocols.

you can't, in a request, send a ressource link and expect the server to download it before resuming request treatment.

Either you download the file from the url and include its content in your request,

**OR**

send the url and have the **code logic** on the server to download it.